# Find the minimum of $xy+yz+zx+\frac1x+\frac2y+\frac5z$ for $x, y, z > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $x,y,z > 0$. What is the smallest value of the below expression?
> \begin{align*}
> xy+yz+zx+\frac1x+\frac2y+\frac5z
> \end{align*}

I tried with Lagrange multiplier but I have not any constraint.

Comment: Your contraints are that $x,y,z$ should be positive... no ? Otherwise you just need to compute the gradient/hessian.

Answer (score 5):

*Remarks*: While we used calculus to motivate our solution (the details are given at the end), we do not need to include any calculus in the solution!

---

Let $a = \frac{x}{z} > 0$ and $b = \frac{y}{z} > 0$ (correspondingly, $x = az, ~ y = bz$).

We have
\begin{align*}
 &xy + yz + zx + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{y} + \frac{5}{z}\\[5pt]
 =\,& z^2(ab + b + a) + \frac{1}{z}\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + 5\right)\\[5pt]
 =\,& z^2(ab + b + a) + \frac{1}{2z}\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + 5\right) + \frac{1}{2z}\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + 5\right)\\[5pt]
 \ge\,& 3\sqrt[3]{z^2(ab + b + a) \cdot \frac{1}{2z}\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + 5\right) \cdot \frac{1}{2z}\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + 5\right)}\\[5pt]
 =\,& 3\sqrt[3]{\frac14(ab + b + a)\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + 5\right)^2}\\
 \ge\,& 3\sqrt[3]{\frac14 \cdot 144}\\
 =\,& 3\cdot 6^{2/3}
\end{align*}
where we have used
$$(ab + b + a)\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + 5\right)^2 \ge 144. \tag{1}$$
(We give two proofs of (1) at the end.)

Also, when $x = \frac13 6^{1/3}, y = \frac12 6^{1/3}, z = 6^{1/3}$, we have $xy + yz + zx + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{y} + \frac{5}{z} = 3 \cdot 6^{2/3}$.

Thus, the minimum of $xy + yz + zx + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{y} + \frac{5}{z}$ is $3\cdot 6^{2/3}$.

We are done.

---

$\phantom{2}$

*The first proof of (1)*:

Letting $a = u/3, b = v/2$, it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &25\,{u}^{3}{v}^{3}+90\,{u}^{3}{v}^{2}+105\,{u}^{2}{v}^{3}+96\,{u}^{3}v
 +99\,u{v}^{3}\\
 &\quad +32\,{u}^{3}+96\,{u}^{2}v+90\,u{v}^{2
 }+27\,{v}^{3} \ge 660\,{u}^{2}{v}^{2}.
\end{align*}
Using AM-GM, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\mathrm{LHS}\\ 
 \ge\,& 660\sqrt[660]{(u^3v^3)^{25} (u^3v^2)^{90}  (u^2v^3)^{105} (u^3v)^{96} (uv^3)^{99} (u^3)^{32}  (u^2v)^{96} (uv^2)^{90} (v^3)^{27}}\\
 =\,& 660u^2v^2.
\end{align*}
(*Note*: $25+90+105+96+99+32+96+90+27 = 660$.)

We are done.

---

*The second proof of (1)*:

Let $u = ab + b + a$. Using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$
\frac{1}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + 5 = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{2 + 2u}{u - a} + 3
\ge \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2+2u})^2}{a + u - a} + 3
= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2+2u})^2}{ u } + 3.
$$
Thus,
$$(ab + b + a)\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + 5\right)^2
\ge u\left(\frac{(1 + \sqrt{2+2u})^2}{u} + 3\right)^2.$$

It suffices to prove that, for all $u > 0$,
$$u\left(\frac{(1 + \sqrt{2+2u})^2}{u} + 3\right)^2 \ge 144.$$

Letting $2 + 2u = v^2$ for $v > \sqrt 2$, we have
$$u\left(\frac{(1 + \sqrt{2+2u})^2}{u} + 3\right)^2 - 144
= \frac{(25v^2 + 140v + 148)(v - 2)^2}{2(v^2 - 2)} \ge 0.$$

We are done.

---

$\phantom{2}$

---

*Details of using calculus to motivate the solution*:

(1) Let $x = az, y = bz$. We have
$$xy + yz + zx + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{y} + \frac{5}{z} =  z^2(ab + b + a) + \frac{1}{z}\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + 5\right).$$
We can appy AM-GM to get
$$xy + yz + zx + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{y} + \frac{5}{z}
\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac14(ab + b + a)\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + 5\right)^2}.$$

We need to find the minimum of
$$f(a, b) := (ab + b + a)\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + 5\right)^2, \quad a, b > 0.$$
We have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial a} &= {\frac { \left( 5\,ab+2\,a+b \right)  \left( 5\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}+7\,{a}^
   {2}b-a{b}^{2}+2\,{a}^{2}-ab-2\,{b}^{2} \right) }{{a}^{3}{b}^{2}}},\\
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial b} &= {\frac { \left( 5\,ab+2\,a+b \right)  \left( 5\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}-2\,{a}^
    {2}b+6\,a{b}^{2}-4\,{a}^{2}-2\,ab+{b}^{2} \right) }{{a}^{2}{b}^{3}}}.
\end{align*}
From $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial b} = 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
 5\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}+7\,{a}^{2}b-a{b}^{2}+2\,{a}^{2}-ab-2\,{b}^{2} &= 0, \tag{2}\\
 5\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}-2\,{a}^{2}b+6\,a{b}^{2}-4\,{a}^{2}-2\,ab+{b}^{2} &= 0. \tag{3}
\end{align*}
$(2) \times (5b^2-2b-4) - (3) \times (5b^2+7b+2)$ gives
$$-b \left( 35\,{b}^{3}a+35\,a{b}^{2}+15\,{b}^{3}-8\,ab+3\,{b}^{2}-8\,a-
6\,b \right) 
 = 0$$
which results in
$$a = -3\,{\frac {b \left( 5\,{b}^{2}+b-2 \right) }{35\,{b}^{3}+35\,{b}^{2}-
  8\,b-8}}.$$
Then (1) becomes
$$-4\,{\frac {{b}^{2} \left( 5\,b+2 \right)  \left( 4\,b+1 \right) 
  \left( 2\,b-1 \right)  \left( 5\,{b}^{2}+5\,b-1 \right) }{ \left( 35
  \,{b}^{2}-8 \right) ^{2} \left( b+1 \right) }}
= 0$$
which results in $b = 1/2$. Then $a = 1/3$.

(2) Early attempt:

We have
\begin{align*}
 xy + yz + zx + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{y} + \frac{5}{z}
 &= (y + z)x + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{y} + yz + \frac{5}{z}\\
 &\ge 2\sqrt{y + z} + \frac{2}{y} + yz + \frac{5}{z}.
\end{align*}
We need to find the minimum of
$$g(y, z) := 2\sqrt{y + z} + \frac{2}{y} + yz + \frac{5}{z}, \quad y, z > 0.$$
We have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{y+z}} - \frac{2}{y^2} + z, \\
 \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{y+z}} + y - \frac{5}{z^2}.
\end{align*}
After some complicated manipulations, we get $y = \frac12 6^{1/3}$ and $z = 6^{1/3}$. If computer is used, the reasoning is simple.

Comment: This is nice, but it does rather seem to come out of nowhere. Can you show us the calculus that motivated it? I tried but I couldn't see how to solve the equations for the gradient=0.

Comment: @Blitzer Thanks for comment. I added some details.

Comment: Thank you. You are very good with the algebraic manipulations!

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a local minimum at $(0.605720276464826, 0.908549253319499, 1.817108635900953)$ [numerical search].

Have you tried to apply the criterion for minima of a scalar function of several variables on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and after that applying your restriction that all input values are positive?

The only zero of the gradient in the first quadrant is at $x=\frac{6^{1/3}}{3},y=\frac{6^{1/3}}{2},z=6^{1/3}$ with value of your function at that point equal to $3\,6^{2/3}\approx 9.905781747$.

Of course we still have do additional work to verify this is the solution.

Comment: The gradient of your function is $\left(\begin{array}{c} y+z-\frac{1}{x^2}\\ x+z-\frac{2}{y^2}\\ x+y-\frac{5}{z^2} \end{array}\right)$ and the Hessian Matrix is $\left(\begin{array}{ccc} \frac{2}{x^3} & 1 & 1\\ 1 & \frac{4}{y^3} & 1\\ 1 & 1 & \frac{10}{z^3} \end{array}\right)$.